# No mapping for GET /index SpringBoot Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am creating the Spring boot registration form application with Thymeleaf. When I run the application I ran into a problem with the stack trace I attached below. I have two issues over here one is the `Student` class with `@jakarta.persistence.Id` and `@Id`. I defined it as look this way otherwise error was displayed.

```
  akarta.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [error]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/error] again.
```

What I tried so far I attached below.

**StudentController**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    StudentService studentService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Home Page");
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveStudent(@ModelAttribute("student") Student std, HttpServletRequest request) {
        studentService.save(std);

        return "redirect:/";
    }

}
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity
public class Student {

    @jakarta.persistence.Id
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String course;
    private String image;

    public Student() { }
```

**StudentService**

```
public interface StudentService {

    public void save(Student std);
}
```

**SeviceIMPL**

```
@Service
public class SeviceIMPL implements StudentService {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository repo;
    @Override
    public void save(Student std) {
        repo.save(std);
    }
}
```

**StudentRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository  extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {

}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="common/header :: header"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div th:replace="common/header :: navbar"/>

<div class="col-sm-4">
    <!--/*@thymesVar id="student" type=""*/-->
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/save}" th:object="${student}" method="post">


        <div alight="left">
            <tr>
                <label class="form-label" >Student Name</label>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" />
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" class="form-control" placeholder="Student Name" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </div>

        <div alight="left">

            <tr>
                <label class="form-label" >Course</label>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{course}" class="form-control" placeholder="Course" /></td>
            </tr>
        </div>
        <div alight="left">
            <tr>
                <label class="form-label" >Fee</label>
                <td><input type="text" th:each="image : {page.content}" class="form-control" placeholder="Fee" /></td>
            </tr>
        </div>
        <br>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Save</button> </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a few errors in the template that may be the cause that the template is not parsed correctly.

- You have many typos `alight` that should be `align`.
- The line `th:each="image : {page.content}"` is certainly not correct and is not a way how to generate a table of images. You might want to use this:

  ```
  <tr th:each="image: ${page.content}">

      <-- First column with the image label-->
      <td th:text="${image.label}"></td>

      <-- Second column with the image itself -->
      <td>
        <img th:src="@{${image.url}}"/>
      </td>
  </tr>
  ```
- Finally I am really not sure whther `@Id` and `@jakarta.persistence.Id` is a good combination. You should either stick to `javax` or `jakarta` based on the dependencies version. However, I am not sure if Thymeleaf is compatible with `jakarta` at all as long as I didn't use Thymeleaf for a long time.

Comment: ya. now i am getting No mapping for GET /index

Comment: if i put only @Id error displayed Persistent entity 'Student' should have primary key

Comment: @Entity' class must declare or inherit at least one '@Id' or '@EmbeddedId' property

Comment: If you use Spring Boot 3.x, then you need to use the `jakarta` classes, not the `javax` classes.